# separate lsof output by column

Tags: text-processing, lsof

I am using this command below and trying to separate the columns I only want to get the PID to use it in my python script.

I can easily get this line by line but then how to separate into columns in a non hacky way?

I can easily split by space but lets face it that is a terrible idea, any suggestions?

```
root@python-VirtualBox:/var/python# lsof | grep TCP
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    3449 root    3u  IPv4  24248      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd    3449 root    4u  IPv6  24257      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `awk` is good for this because it splits fields for you:

```
lsof | awk '$8 == "TCP" { print $2 }'
```

If field 8 is "TCP", then print field 2.

Comment: See also https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lsof&sektion=8&manpath=linux#OUTPUT_FOR_OTHER_PROGRAMS

Comment: …unless some column is empty, because awk cannot detect that, and will shift the remaining columns left :/

Answer (score 10):

The `lsof` command is quite full-featured, allowing you to specify many different search criteria. In particular, the `-i` option lets you search by Internet address, including protocol, rendering `grep` unnecessary. So you could replace

```
lsof | grep TCP
```

with

```
lsof -i TCP
```

`lsof` also allows you to specify which fields you are interested in with the `-F` option and only output those (one on each line). So we can do

```
lsof -i TCP -F 'p'
```

to output a list of PIDs for processes which are using TCP.

However, each of these PIDs is prefixed with a "p" (e.g. "p156"), so finally we can use `cut` to just get the numerical ID. This gives us a final command of

```
lsof -i TCP -F 'p' | cut -c 2-
```

Of course @RobertL's answer is also perfectly fine, but I like to challenge myself to not use AWK to solve all my text-processing challenges.

Answer (score 3):

### in:

```
lsof -iTCP -Fp
```

### out:

```
p1135                                
p6326                                                                  
p16841                                                                 
p18130                                                                 
p37908                                                                 
p41768                                                                 
p51944                                                                 
p71882                                                                 
p74759                                                                 
p79636                                                                 
p82203
```

Comment: Why vote this down? It's correct, and provides all results, unlike `lsof |grep TCP`.

Comment: Probably because the same answer was already given with more details and a command to strip the 'p' prefix just hours before your answered.  I gave you an upvote to compensate, because brevity is also a virtue :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option (`-t`) to list only PIDs. Combined with the `-i` option to filter TCP, it should do what you wanted (and no need to remove the 'p' prefix from the `-F` option):

```
lsof -i TCP -t
```

**Output**:

```
1
651
652
728
942
947
958
959
[...]
```

**Version**:

```
lsof -v
lsof version information:
    revision: 4.93.2
[...]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only truly safe option is to use e.g. `lsof -F0pn` and then parse the output with some other programming language. In that case, lsof will emit fields separated by null bytes and every field starts with a character that specifies the type of the field. For example `p123<NULL>n/var/log/syslog<NULL>` would mean that PID 123 has open file name called `/var/log/syslog`. Note that if the process has multiple files open, the `p` (PID) field will be listed only once and multiple `n` (name) fields will appear describing the files.

Also note that even if you request fields `p` and `n` with the `-F` flag, `lsof` may emit additional fields, too, so be prepared to be ignore the fields you're not interested in.

The `lsof` is part of POSIX spec and it has this weird behavior due historical reasons: https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/8/lsof/

Comment: Why is this the only "truly safe" option? Why are the other answers not "safe" (enough)?

Comment: The answers that respond to literal question (that is use *text processing* to separate the columns) cannot work without using the `-F` flag because there are no real columns in `lsof` output. In addition, without the flag `0` for the `-F`, embedded linefeeds in command name or in the filename of `lsof` output will cause incorrect interpreation of the data. If you don't answer the original text processing question but only list the PIDs, then `lsof -i TCP -t` is definitely okay.